# Adding up specific probabilities from a Python's Pandas DataFrame based on a 4 element list index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
               Pr(X,O)
(H, H, H, H)  0.042743
(H, H, H, C)  0.003664
(H, H, C, H)  0.073274
(H, H, C, C)  0.021982
(H, C, H, H)  0.005234
(H, C, H, C)  0.000449
(H, C, C, H)  0.031403
(H, C, C, C)  0.009421
(C, H, H, H)  0.113982
(C, H, H, C)  0.009770
(C, H, C, H)  0.195398
(C, H, C, C)  0.058619
(C, C, H, H)  0.048849
(C, C, H, C)  0.004187
(C, C, C, H)  0.293096
(C, C, C, C)  0.087929
```

Unfortunately this was generated by code that is too big to post in this question. Notice that I have all possibilities of two elements (`H` and `C` ) in a sequence of four as the DataFrame index. My question is, what is the best way to add up all the numbers with each element in each position?

For example. Consider position `0` and element `H`. Here I would sum
`0.042743 + 0.003664 + 0.073274 + 0.021982 + 0.005234 + 0.000449 + 0.031403 + 0.009421` which equals 0.1887. I'd then like to do the same for `C` in the same position then again in all positions. (Obviously I could take the complement but I'd like to do this again in the future with more that a two letter alphabet).

A desired outcome would be another pandas DataFrame which looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: is `(H, H, H, H)` a tuple or a string?

Comment: It was a tuple generated from `itertools.product`. Not sure if pandas converts it to string though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to do it with taking the result of `itertools.product` as a MultiIndex.

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(itertools.product(('H', 'C'), repeat=4))
```

We then groupby by the different levels, and concatenate them.

```
pd.concat( [df.groupby(level=[i]).sum().rename(columns={'Pr(X,O)': i}) for i in range(4)] , axis=1)

         0         1         2         3
C  0.81183  0.480568  0.771122  0.196021
H  0.18817  0.519432  0.228878  0.803979
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to MaxU's comment, no need to take a MultiIndex with a little operation on the index as a Series.

Comment: It's a beautiful solution! Here is your solution, which should also work with the OP's original index: `pd.concat([x.groupby(x.index.str[i]).sum().rename(columns={'Pr(X,O)':i}) for i in range(len(x.index[0]))], axis=1)`

Comment: Both fantastic answers, very elegant. Thanks

Comment: Thank you ! Where we see that pandas is not really pythonic, as there is sometimes a thousand ways to do the same thing^^

Answer (score 1):

You can first create new columns from `tuples`, then [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and last [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc=sum`:

```
df['a'],df['b'],df['c'],df['d'] = zip(*df.index)

print (df)
               Pr(X,O)  a  b  c  d
(H, H, H, H)  0.042743  H  H  H  H
(H, H, H, C)  0.003664  H  H  H  C
(H, H, C, H)  0.073274  H  H  C  H
(H, H, C, C)  0.021982  H  H  C  C
(H, C, H, H)  0.005234  H  C  H  H
(H, C, H, C)  0.000449  H  C  H  C
(H, C, C, H)  0.031403  H  C  C  H
(H, C, C, C)  0.009421  H  C  C  C
(C, H, H, H)  0.113982  C  H  H  H
(C, H, H, C)  0.009770  C  H  H  C
(C, H, C, H)  0.195398  C  H  C  H
(C, H, C, C)  0.058619  C  H  C  C
(C, C, H, H)  0.048849  C  C  H  H
(C, C, H, C)  0.004187  C  C  H  C
(C, C, C, H)  0.293096  C  C  C  H
(C, C, C, C)  0.087929  C  C  C  C

print (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Pr(X,O)'])
         .pivot_table(index='value', columns='variable', values='Pr(X,O)', aggfunc=sum))

variable        a         b         c         d
value                                          
C         0.81183  0.480568  0.771122  0.196021
H         0.18817  0.519432  0.228878  0.803979
```

Or if need column names as `int` and remove index and column names, use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Pr(X,O)'])
         .pivot_table(index='value', columns='variable', values='Pr(X,O)', aggfunc=sum)
         .rename_axis(None)
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

         0         1         2         3
C  0.81183  0.480568  0.771122  0.196021
H  0.18817  0.519432  0.228878  0.803979
```